# How to deal with missing column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I'm writing a function in Ruby to pull data from multiple tables and then inserting those values into a "master" table. The problem is that not all the tables have the same schema. Specifically, some of the tables have "Column X" while others are missing it. How can I use the same query to select data from both tables, yet deal with the fact that the column may or may not be present? I tried the following CASE, but it does not seem to work:

```
select case
         when column_x is not null then sum(column_x)
         else null
    end case
```

Comment: You can just add a `NULL` column to your `SELECT` ?

Comment: You can't use the same query with tables like this.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO I wish! Unfortunately, I didn't create the tables, and the "owner" won't add it. :(

Comment: @Barmar if that is actually the answer, can you just write it as an answer and I'll select it? Good to know.

Comment: @EvanZamir Barmar answered it.

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO And I accepted it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use the same query for all tables if they differ like this.

An easy solution would be to add column X to the other tables, and just leave null values in it. When you write `SUM(column_x)` in the query, it will be `NULL` for those tables.

Otherwise, if you're combining all the tables using a `UNION`, you can add `NULL` for these tables:

```
SELECT column_x, column_y, column_z FROM table1
UNION
SELECT NULL, column_y, column_z FROM table2
```

If you're doing separate queries from Ruby, you can conditionalize it on the table name. When it creates the query that reads from one of the tables with no `column_x`, it can add `NULL column_x` to the `SELECT` clause, so that the code that processes the result doesn't need to distinguish the tables.